# Probability: Counting people with no precise sensors

Tags: probability

I have a simple probability problem that I don't know how to solve...

I have a room with 4 doors. The doors have a sensor counting people ( ingressing and egressing ) . The sensors have an accuracy of 94% .

So, people in the room P = S1 + S2 + S3 + S4

If during a day can pass through the room 10.000 people,

can I assure there won't be more than ie 150 people in the room ?

What drift in the counter should I expect ?

Comment: Each sensor have an accuracy of 0.94% ? And the sensors are working indepenently ? And what do you mean by "can I assure there won't be more than ie 150 people in the room ?"

Comment: You have not sufficiently described the probability distribution of entering and exiting people at each door (or the "process" that is generating the movements of such people).  What exactly do you want to know?  What is the lowest sensor reading that will provide a high degree of confidence (i.e., high probability) that there are less than 150 people in the room??

Comment: @callculus, with 94% accuracy I mean the sensor can show 94 people when entering 100. The solution is for security purposes: I need to assure that no more than 150 people are in the room in an instant.

Comment: @Andrew gray, You are right. I don't have the prob distribution. This is a museum with continuous people moving . The sensors are counting how people ingress (+1) or egress (-1) through the doors to the room. So, I cannot count people in the room. I can just count people crossing doors. 150 people in the room is maximum availability for security reasons.

Comment: OK well you still need to model the people moving through each door either using a probability distribution or some random generator (which would simulate the distribution).  Then given the traffic patterns (and traffic density through each door) , you can determine how long it will take for the sensor to "drift" by a given amount.

Comment: @callculus - Sensors are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot assure this. Here's an worst-case example flow to show that. It shows that if everyone uses door 1, it's possible to have a too-large error. Suppose that at the start of the day:

> 100 people enter; sensor says 100.
>
> 94 people leave; sensor says that 100 people left.

After this pair of actions, there are $6$ people left in the room, but the sensor total says "$0$".

During this pair of actions, about $100$ people have 'passed through' the room. So over the course of the day, the same action can occur $100$ times, for a total of $10,000$ visitors.

At the end of those 100 iterations, you'll have $600$ people left in the room.

So the sensors, in a worst-case situation, are not good enough to ensure that no more than $150$ people are in the room.

NB: It may be that the pair of actions I've described counts as approximately $200$ 'passing through' events. Then you can only repeat $50$ times...but you still end up with $300$ people in the room.